# How to Enable USB Debugging on Nexus Player? (Android TV)

Tags: android, adb, google-cast, android-tv, nexus-player

I am trying to debug my app on the Nexus Player hardware. I enabled the developer mode, turned USB Debugging on, and connected the cable. However, I don't see any message like the one below as stated here:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_tv#adb-usb

In the Allow USB debugging? dialog, select Always allow from this computer, and select OK.

What steps might be missing? Could it be a problem with the USB driver?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Single Language, 64-bit

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the device and/or your PC?

Comment: Yes, but it did not help. I will buy a new cable and retry.

Comment: for some `adb` connection trouble-shooting tips read http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Comment: Well, I ran the command suggested at the blog post, and the output is: 

Name     : Android
DeviceID : USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE7\584228CC
Service  :

So, I guess something is not configured on my laptop...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed the Google USB Driver in Device Manager (Computer Management), and it worked. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I fixed it by simply using a USB cable that supports data transfers. The cable that comes along with the Nexus Player is a 'charging' cable type.